# Узнать букву диска зная адрес шары

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Допустим, есть `\\share\lala` , как мне программно узнать какой букве диска на сервере соответствует данная шара?

Comment: в смысле? вы знаете адрес шары и хотите узнать с какого диска она раздается или у вас шара подключена как сетевой диск к удаленной машине и нужно узнать букву диска с которой сопоставлена эта шара на удаленной машине?

Comment: @rdorn у меня адрес шары и хочу с какого диска она раздается на сервере

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это можно сделать через WMI для которого в .NET есть обертка.

Вам понадобится добавить в проект ссылку на `System.Management.DLL` и указать в коде `using System.Management;`

Выведем все имеющиеся "шары" с указанием полного пути к локальной папке

```
var oManager = new ManagementClass("Win32_Share");
foreach(ManagementObject oShare in oManager.GetInstances())
{
    var strShareName = oShare
        .Properties
        .Cast<PropertyData>()
        .First(x => x.Name == "Name")
        .Value.ToString();
    var strSharePath = oShare
        .Properties
        .Cast<PropertyData>()
        .First(x => x.Name == "Path")
        .Value.ToString();
    if(strSharePath == "")
        strSharePath = "***UNDEFINED***";
    Console.WriteLine(strShareName + " - " + strSharePath);
}
```

`strPath` будет содержать полный путь к шаре, из которого достать букву диска уже совсем просто - например так:

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(strSharePath);
Console.WriteLine(di.Root);
```

Добавив совсем немного кода, можно сделать поиск данных "шары" по ее сетевому имени.

Приведенный пример позволяет узнать пути к общим папкам на локальной машине, однако WMI позволяет также обращаться к удаленным машинам, при наличии соответствующих прав у пользователя и необходимых разрешениях на удаленной машине. Подробнее про удаленное подключение и безопасность WMI в документации на MSDN **[тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa389290(v=vs.85).aspx)** и **[тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa393266(v=vs.85).aspx)**

Идея взята с [**pinvoke.net**](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32.NetShareGetInfo), там вообще много интересного по использованию WinAPI под .NET