# Как понимать работу WCF на примере клиент-серверной архитектуре в локальной сети

Tags: wcf

После прочтения некоторой литературы о WCF так и не понял кое-что.
Задача. Локальная сеть с 10 компьютерами. Решил производить некие манипуляции с компьютерами, управляя ими с одного компьютера. Для этого решил использовать технологию WCF.
   Вопросы:

1. Я хочу обойтись без всяких серверов и хостингов. На обычных компьютерах клиент-служба бы висела в памяти, а сервер-служба бы слушала их и давала бы сигнал. Как я понимаю, что для этого более подходит т.н. selfie-hosted.
2. И как узнают службы друг друга? Мне кажется, что сервер ждет и слушает, а клиент посылает сигнал, что он активен.

Извините, но хочу понять суть WCF на примере локальной сети.

Comment: Для выполнения "неких" действий можно использовать WCF, вопрос в том, что за действия вы собираетесь производить с компьютерами. Уточните подробности, можно пример предполагаемых действий и результата, а то тема слишком широкая. Вечером напишу подробно, если конечно ни кто раньше не отпишется и будет конкретика.

Comment: Имеется локальная сеть с 10 компьютерами. Хочу с одного компьютера управлять остальными компьютерами. А значит, нужно использовать сервер-клиентскую архитектуру.
Действия служб таковы: 1. С сервера посылается мной команда всем компьютерам. 2. Остальные компьютеры принимают команду.
А команды таковы: 1. Заблокировать компьютер, "заморозив" клавиатуру и мышь, а также отключить возможность перезагружать компьютер. 2. Разблокировать компьютеры. 3 Выключать компьютеры.

Comment: По этим условиям выходит, что не требуется IIS. На сервере команды будут слаться через winfowm или wpf. А клиентские службы бы висели в процессе и слушали, при получении команды выполняли бы команду. С остальными командами я сам разберусь.

Comment: Переформулируйте заголовок пожалуйста, он не информативен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. С сервера посылается мной команда всем компьютерам. 2. Остальные компьютеры принимают команду.

Для администрирования и удаленного управления на практике лучше использовать технологию `WMI`. Это потребует произвести некоторые настройки для разрешения удаленного взаимодействия на управляемых компьютерах, на этом работ с подчиненными машинами завершается. Теперь для управления можно использовать как обычную консоль или `PowerShell`, так и написать удобную оболочку на .NET. Для работы с `WMI` существует пространство имен `System.Management` в сборке `System.Management.DLL`. Небольшой пример можно подсмотреть в этом [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/544701/198316)

> 1. Заблокировать компьютер, "заморозив" клавиатуру и мышь, а также отключить возможность перезагружать компьютер. 2. Разблокировать компьютеры.

боюсь что это вряд ли возможно стандартными средствами, во всяком случае в .NET вы таких средств не найдете и придется подключать неуправляемые библиотеки, если таковые обнаружатся. Тем более не возможно защититься от перезагрузки кнопкой `reset` или отключением питания. Если бы Windows умел цеплять клавиатуру и мышь на ходу, можно было бы что-то придумать с временным отключением устройств, но это приведет к полной потере устройств ввода и необходимости в перезагрузке. Можно запустить специальную программу в режиме оболочки, и блокировать ввод на ней, но во-первых, такая "блокировка элементарно обходится и вернуться в рабочий стол не составляет труда если у вас есть диалоговые окна для открытия файлов, сомневаюсь что вы планируете работать без использования файлов; во-вторых вы лишаете своих пользователей возможности пользоваться другими программами. В общем, ИМХО, эта затея бесполезная. Я работал в школе, есть более эффективные методы удержать внимание, если это не ваш случай, чтож, приношу свои извинения, медиум из меня отвратительный %).

> 3 Выключать компьютеры.

Эту функцию прекрасно можно выполнять и из обычной консоли или оболочки. Равно как и включать, но для этого уже потребуется дополнительная настройка в `BIOS`.

**Можно ли все это прикрутить к WCF**

Можно. Вам потребуется запустить сервис на управляемых машинах и обращаться к запущенным сервисам с "админской" машины. При этом фактически клиентом в данном случае будет программка для управления, а все управляемые - серверами. Для выполнения отдельных команд вам все равно придется обращаться либо к `WMI`, либо к `WinAPI`, т.к. управляемый код .NET далеко не всемогущ. Поэтому стоит или не стоит использовать `WCF` решать конечно вам, но задачи управления - не та область для которой он предназначен. В качестве альтернативы стоит посмотреть на службы Windows, которые также можно создавать в .NET, пользы от них будет существенно больше, да и отключить ее не так просто если все правильно сделать.

Если в сети есть домен с ActiveDirectory, то большую часть задач по контролю за действиями пользователя и конфигурированием рабочего места, можно переложить на групповые политики, что сильно снижает расход времени на индивидуальную настройку каждого рабочего места.

**Зачем тогда вообще нужен WCF?**

В основном для предоставления высокоуровневого API для доступа к различным ресурсам, таким например, как базы данных, для того чтобы отвязать клиента от конкретного вида БД. Т.е. клиентам не будет ни какой разницы что лежит за сервисом - Orace, MS SQL или просто набор файлов.

Надеюсь мне удалось дать обще представление о способах решения вашей задачи в целом.

Comment: Вы правы в отношении школы. Да, я работаю в школе. Ну, у меня такая задумка: на компьютере ученика предупреждает, что до окончания урока осталось 5  минут. Потом после звонка полностью блокируется экран с помощью WinForm или WPF. Потом, после начала очередного урока, все это разблокируется. Ну, это как в интернет-кафе.
Поэтому и спросил. Не хотел весь проект размещать здесь, уж лучше кусочками решать проект.
P.S. А работаю в школе для глухих и слабослышащих детей.

Comment: @GhostBasenji у меня есть некоторые практические наработки по организации рабочих мест и эффективному использованию отвратительного железа, могу поделиться если есть необходимость

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ

Comment: @GhostBasenji теоретически, сам не делал, можно попробовать сделать то что вы хотите. Для этого хватит обычного UDPListener-а для получения команд. Нужна форма, которая будет открываться на весь экран в монопольном режиме. Но это пожалуй лучше отдельным вопросом.